# Trailing string in name of temporary directories

Tags: systemd, tmp

I've found that systemd private directory names of ends with a string, for example:

```
systemd-private-3108aa34ce664b6dbb374430ba5f0592-mariadb.service-Q78z1I
```

What does mean such a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging around in [The Source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd) reveals

```
./src/core/namespace.c:        x = strjoin(prefix, "/systemd-private-", sd_id128_to_string(boot_id, bid), "-", id, "-XXXXXX", NULL);
```

which one might eventually chase down as a relation to the [`mktemp(3)`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man3/mktemp.3) call that creates (a hopefully) unique file that a local attacker with write access to the parent directory will have difficulty guessing or creating in advance.

Six X's might be considered short; OpenBSD developers instead recommend 10 X's, though the ideal number depends on the filesystem, how diligent an attacker can be in creating all the possibilities (if they can create most or all of the possibilities, then that could be a denial-of-service), versus how many inodes the filesystem allows, and how diligently the directory in question is monitored for absurd numbers of files (or exhaustion of inodes). Use the [mathematical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) to figure out how many potential files a given number of X's allows for a given number of input characters (usually alphanumeric plus underscore).

Comment: Greate explanation, I've found in Linux man page that mkstemp is better. Also, I guess in this case the tool is [mkdtemp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp).